# Proof of linear independence in a complex vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification

I am trying to prove the following:

Let $V$ be a complex vector space and let $u,v \in V$.

Suppose $w_1 := u + iv$ and $w_2 := u - iv$ are linearly independent, then $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent.

I have tried using the definition of linear independence:

$c_1 \cdot w_1 + c_2 \cdot w_2 = 0$, and then $c_1$ and $c_2$ equals $0$.

$c_1 \cdot (u + iv) + c_2 \cdot  (u - iv) = 0$

$u \cdot (c_1 + c_2) + iv \cdot (c_1-c_2) = 0$

I dont know where to go from there.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. You can format maths with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

You should assume $c_1 u + c_2 v = 0$ and try to get $c_1 = c_2 = 0$.

The relations $u = \frac{w_1+w_2}{2}$ and $v = \frac{w_1-w_2}{2i}$ should be helpful.

Comment: I then get $c_1 = c_2 = 0$, but what does that prove?

Comment: @john This proves that $\{u,v\}$ is linearly independent by definition: $$\alpha u + \beta v = 0 \implies \alpha = \beta = 0$$

Comment: But how do i know that neither $u$ nor $b$ are equal $0$?

Comment: @john If $u = 0$ then you would have $w_1 = iv$ and $w_2 = -iv$, so $\{w_1, w_2\}$ is not linearly independent. If $v = 0$ then you would have $w_1 = w_2 = u$ so again $\{w_1, w_2\}$ is not linearly independent. But you don't have to check this separately, if any of $u,v$ is zero you wouldn't be able to get $c_1 = c_2 = 0$.

Answer (score 0):

May be it's easily to prove that if $u$ $v$ are linearly dependent then $u+iv$ and $u-iv$ are linearly dependent.

So there exists $(a,b)\ne (0,0)$ such that
$$au+bv=0$$
Then
$$(a-ib)(u+iv)+(a+ib)(u-iv)=2au+2bv=0$$